# "Rounding" GPS coordinates based on uncertainty range

Tags: coordinates, gps, algorithm

A stationary GPS receiver will produce a random cluster of coordinate points around its actual location. I can look at previous coordinate readings and apply various algorithms to find the "average" position, but I have a different idea I'm trying to explore: If I know the uncertainty radius of the coordinates, I should be able to "round" the coordinates to that level of uncertainty to provide a slightly coarser coordinate that is actually a better approximation of the actual position of the receiver.

Example: If the uncertainty range is 100m, then I need to "round" my coordinates to a 100m "grid", as having coordinates with more resolution than 100m gives me "false accuracy".

Is there an algorithm to do this calculation?

I know I can simply chop off decimal-degree digits, but this level of "rounding" doesn't really let me match the current uncertainty range.

Comment: Though it is a nice idea, in my own experience the accuracy values only correlates to some extent with real position accuracy, and I would for sure not use it for stripping decimal places or snap to 100 meter grid - though depends on use case. Something more on gps accuracy value here - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/how-correct-is-the-accuracy-value-given-by-gps-devices. My recommendation - if you want to somehow include the accuracy parameter, go with symbology -graduated or categorized symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you could save the GPS reported precision in an attribute, convert it from m to degrees using 111km per degree latitude (and multiplying by cos(latitude) for longitude). Then you could use the `log10` function to convert the error to number of significant digits and finally `round` or `format_number` to display the GPS coordinates suitably
rounded.

However, while eg handheld phones and other consumer units routinely report a precision of 5m, or about 1/20000 of a degree latitude, the accuracy is often less due to multipath or other systematic errors. So I’m not sure how useful this type of calculation would be.

---

On reread, it seems you may have your coords in m already, so that step was already done in this instance. The rest still applies.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I don't think simple rounding is the right solution. What I'm pursuing now is "binning", essentially "snapping" a given coordinate to a regular grid of coordinates (the grid being set by the desired resolution). This is showing some promise, but more experimentation is needed.